# Service Stack (4.0.40.0 - Version) error when I join 3 tables to extract data from 2 of the 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using service stack ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer to extract data from SQL DB. I am joining 3 tables but I need data only from 2 of the 3 tables. When I execute the Query I get the following error. I looked up the service stack examples and everything seems to be the same but still I get the error.
Am I missing anything?

Error:

> 'AT.Data.Model.Veh' does not contain a definition for
>   'Created'

StackTrace:

```
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at AT.Data.Layer.ATSQLRepository.FetchData() in C:*****.cs:line 446" string
```

Here is the Query:

```
var response = dbconnection.From<Veh>()
    .Join<Veh, Dist>((v, d) => v.VehID == d.VehID)
    .Join<Dist, Deal>((dist, deal) => dist.DistID == deal.DistID)
    .Where(x => x.VehID == "B")
    .And<Dist>(dist.St.ToUpper() == "Z")
    .And<Deal>(deal => deal.St.ToUpper() == "X")
    .Select<Veh, Deal>((v, deal) => new {v.VAL,deal.Created});

var results = dbconnection.Select(response);
```

Comment: Can you confirm if this is still an issue with the latest v4.5.12 on NuGet?

Comment: Well, my team is restricted to this version of Service stack. That is the main reason I mentioned the service stack version number.

Comment: If your query works in the latest v4.5.12 than we can tell its an issue that's been resolved already. If it's still an issue with the latest version then please provide a stand-alone repro that we can run locally. BTW since you've got a Custom Select, you need to either select into a POCO that matches the Custom Schema that's being selected, otherwise you need to select the results into a [dynamic result set](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#dynamic-result-sets).

Comment: Mythz, thank you for your suggestion. Creating a POCO class helped. But there is one more challenge regarding ambiguous column name, Class DISThave a column ID and Class DEAL have a column ID. When I get the data from the DB, I need DEAL.ID but I always get a DIST.ID, How to resolve the ambiguous Column issue?

Comment: Then this issue is likely already resolved in the latest version, if you want to stick to the older version you'll likely need to drop down to execute Custom SQL.

Comment: Thanks Mythz for you help